# How to configure the right collection path for Algolia?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, algolia, firebase-extensions

I have collection in firestore and i want add Firebase's [Search with Algolia](https://extensions.dev/extensions/algolia/firestore-algolia-search) Extension.

[image: Here screenshot for collection]

What is the right path for indexing all announcements with subcollections here?
[image: this field]

Comment: Can you explain "all announcements collection"? Like any collections named "announcements" including sub-collections? I don't think watching collectionGroups() is possible.

Comment: For example  in announcements collection i have  subcollection (e.x articles) - this subcollection have list with articles, also i have another sub collections. I want to indexing all subcollection in announcements  collection (announcements/announcements announcements/articles etc)

Comment: No, the extension just uses Firestore trigger to add/update documents in Algolia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search/blob/main/extension.yaml#L70-L80) for the <kbd>Collection Path</kbd> field it seems that you can specify a path to any collection. Since your announcements are in a top-level collection, the value would be `announcements`.

If you want to target a subcollection, that'd be three path segments, e.g. `announcements/announcements/list`. The second `announcements` in there is the ID of the document whose `list` subcollection to synchronize to Algolia.

Comment: when i type announcements/ i have validation error - Firestore collection paths must be an odd number of segments separated by slashes, e.g. "path/to/collection". Can i use something seems like announcements/*/list ?

Comment: Oops, that part about a trailing slash should not have been in my answer. I updated it now. ---
And from what I could determine you can only specify a single collection (although you can install the extension multiple times to get multiple collections). The repo for the extension would be a good place to file a feature request: https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search